# Cannot init the Global object

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

I am converting a Play 2.3 project to Play 2.4, and replaced the previous Global object with an ErrorHandler, as described in the migration guide. However, when I try to run the project, I get an error:

```
Cannot init the Global object

No source available, here is the exception stack trace:
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Global$.play$api$GlobalSettings$_setter_$play$api$GlobalSettings$$dhehCache_$eq(Lscala/Function1;)V
     play.api.GlobalSettings$class.$init$(GlobalSettings.scala:33)
     Global$.<init>(Global.scala:52)
     Global$.<clinit>(Global.scala)
     sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
     sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
     sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:142)
     java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1088)
     java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1069)
     java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
.....
```

And so on.

There is no Global object in the project, but as I understand it, that is how it's supposed to be (since they're being deprecated). I've done a clean compile, etc., but doesn't help.

Any thoughts about where I should start looking for the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this problem; eventually found a dependency which was trying to use a GlobalSettings object. Removing that fixed the issue.